# Python gdal.Warp trouble with proj.db

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, ubuntugis

I want to use Python gdal.Warp to convert raster projection but I have some problems and i don't know where I have wrong because I define path for `proj.db` and I take some error.

Any idea?

code :

```
import gdal
def convert_data()
    fn = '/home/username/Desktop/raster.tif'
    out = '/home/username/Desktop/raster2.tif'
    gdal.Warp(out, fn, srcSRS="EPSG:4326", dstSRS="EPSG:32614")

convert_data()
```

Error :

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
EPSG:4326
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resampl.py", line 29, in <module>
    convert_data()
  File "resampl.py", line 24, in convert_data
    gdal.Warp(out, fn, srcSRS="EPSG:4326", dstSRS="EPSG:32614")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 596, in Warp
    return wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 3059, in wrapper_GDALWarpDestName
    return _gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args)
TypeError: in method 'wrapper_GDALWarpDestName', argument 4 of type 'GDALWarpAppOptions *'
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

version

```
Python 3.8.10 
GDAL= 3.0.4 
Pyproj=3.1.0  
QGIS=3.20
OS=ubuntu 20.04
```

PATH:

```
export GDAL_DATA=/usr/share/gdal/
export PROJ_LIB=usr/share/proj/
```

Comment: And you can confirm that proj.db is in usr/share/proj/?

Comment: @GBG  proj.db exists in that path usr/share/proj/

Comment: Maybe check that you have ownership of the files?   https://askubuntu.com/questions/175054/how-to-find-owner-and-group-of-a-directory     https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership